# Match consecutive lines that start with 1 or more spaces

Tags: regex, preg-replace

Could anyone offer up assistance to make this work:
https://regex101.com/r/s1X84J/1

**REGEX**

```
^((?:(?:[ ]{1,}|\t).*(\R|$))+){1,}
```

It should match any consecutive lines that start with one or more spaces. In the example, I am able to get it to match the first block of text. I am trying to get it to match the next block of consecutive text starting with one or more spaces as Match 2.

Comment: add the 'g' option?

Comment: How about [`preg_replace('/(?:^[ \t].*\n?)+/m', '***', $str)`](https://regex101.com/r/n4NdWl/1)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need the global flag/option set (/g) to return more than one match.

Secondly the following returns multiple lines starting with space.  It uses a look back to ensure the match starts on an even line boundary:

```
/(^|(?<=\n))( [^\n]*\n\r?)+  /gm
```

The flags are on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `g` and `m` flag with the following pattern:

```
^\h.*(?:\R\h.*)*
```

If your real regex flavor does not support `\h` (horizontal whitespaces) you can use either `[^\S\r\n]` or `[\p{Zs}\t]` instead.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\h` - a horizontal whitespaces
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\R\h.*)*` - any zero or more occurrences of

  - `\R` - any line break sequence
  - `\h` - a horizontal whitespaces
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

It needs to be adjusted if the regex flavor is not PCRE / Onigmo / Java.